# Cryptic Family Reunion: Is the election over yet?

Tags: knowledge, cryptic-clues

The answer to this puzzle is a list of ten thematically related words or proper names or phrases. Each of these is clued cryptically, and the theme is to be determined; in this puzzle, the clues are in a particular order relevant to the theme, which is also to be determined. Since the definition part of a cryptic clue would give away the theme, these cryptic clues use a family member (e.g., mom, sister) to stand in for the definition part of the clue. So for example, if the theme of the puzzle were chemical elements, "Sister picking at nit" would clue "tin". I hope you enjoy!

1. Nana to watch latest Cub flop with Pappy (8)
2. Uncle Colin is swerving in lane (7)
3. Mom serves up orange juice and fresh chicken feet to son (7)
4. Dad's \$1,000 replaces Dodge Coronet with Tesla (5)
5. Brother has dominated you (5)
6. Cousin is one caught in shredding of red flag (8)
7. "Start hurrying to shelter, son" (6)
8. Granddad reported to hold on to farm (9)
9. Uncle Noah invites Sir Robin Hood sailing (8)
10. Sister is able to integrate, even $\delta$ (9)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are all:

> surnames of **US PRESIDENTS**.

Explanations:

> 1. Nana to watch latest Cub flop with Pappy (8) **BUCHANAN** = (NANA + (watc)H + CUB)<
>
>  2. Uncle Colin is swerving in lane (7) **LINCOLN** = COLIN* in LN (‘lane’)
>
>  3. Mom serves up orange juice and fresh chicken feet to son (7) **JOHNSON** = OJ< + (fres)H + (chicke)N + SON
>
>  4. Dad's $1,000 replaces Dodge Coronet with Tesla (5) **GRANT** = GRAN(D(odge) --> T)
>
>  5. Brother has dominated you (5) **HAYES** = HAS around YE
>
>  6. Cousin is one caught in shredding of red flag (8) **GARFIELD** = (I + REDFLAG)*
>
>  7. "Start hurrying to shelter, son" (6) – **ARTHUR** = _ART HUR_
>
>  8. Granddad reported to hold on to farm (9) **CLEVELAND** = sounds like ‘CLEAVE LAND’
>
>  9. Uncle Noah invites Sir Robin Hood sailing (8) **HARRISON** = (NOAH + SIR + R(obin))*
>
>  10. Sister is able to integrate, even δ (9) **CLEVELAND** again! = CAN around LEVEL (‘even’) + D

In fact...

> ...these are **consecutive** US Presidents, numbers 15 through 24, which wonderfully includes both of Grover Cleveland's two non-consecutive terms!

Comment: Got 'em all! Any idea on the ordering? Might help with why #10 is there.

Comment: @JeremyDover Ah yes, funny I hadn't even spotted that additional feature...!

Comment: The US did a presidential dollar coin series recently, and they actually did two separate coins for Cleveland. I am probably the only person here that actually cared :-) Checkmark is yours!